# Using mermaid to create tree graphs (specifically syllable trees and syntax trees)

Tags: charts, tree, mermaid, obsidian

I have been looking for a way to dynamically create tree graphs quickly when notetaking for phonetics and syntax. I had been using the Obsidian TikzJax plugin to do so but this is time consuming and does not fit in style with the rest of the text. I learned that mermaid is built into Obsidian and immediately tried it. Unfortunately I am not sure how to do certain things with it.

This is a reference diagram I created using TikzJax, note the split lines on the nucleus node. Each node is not drawn, only the text is visible. Ideally these diagrams would also have the connections coming out of the bottom and attaching to the top of nodes with straight lines. (Using alternative characters as TikzJax does not support Unicode or TIPA)
[image]

**Here** is what I have been able to do with mermaid (so far), it is lacking many of the necessary features.
[image]

Additionally, not being able to do triangular connections in syntax trees is a huge hindrance.
[image]

TLDR; Can mermaid be optimised for syllable and syntax trees? Is it possible to create nodes with no border? Is it possible to make nodes connect at the top and bottom? and is there anyway to do custom connections like the split nucleus or the triangle connection?